# Way to make a div only print at a certain height?

Tags: html, css

I'm printing a form that contains two main divs. One will be cut from the paper once it printed and the other one just contains information about clients. The problem is that the second div's size depends on the amount of information we have on the client themselves. So if we have a lot of information about a particular client, we would need to print muli-pages. Wanting to save paper, having double-sided is fine with us. Is there a way or trick with css that we can make it where the second div will continue at a certain height if a muli-page print is needed so that when we cut the first div, none of the information about the client is cut out too. Below is a simple picture of the desired outcome layout where the red box is what going to be cut, the blue box would be where the client's information would be, and the dash line red box would be just empty space.

[Desired Outcome Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZvGR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@page` css rule to set a margin on all pages besides the first. Margins are given in cm like `margin-top: 10cm;`

```
@page:not(:first) {
    margin-top: <<height of the red div>>;

}
```

Note that `@page` does not allow defining any pages besides the first, so this top gap will still be present on the 3rd, 4th, etc. pages.

Also note that `@page` does not have support for safari and possibly other browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: Is there a workaround for those browsers that may not support the CSS rule?